# MySQL On Duplicate Update Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have run into a unique issue with ON DUPLICATE UPDATE
**My table structure is:**

```
ID = bigint(20) Primary key / Auto Increment<br>
uName = char(20);
```

**Additional Index:**

```
uName_Unique = uName Unique<br>
```

**Table data:**

```
ID = uName<br>
1 = Test01<br>
2 = Test02<br>
3 = Test03<br>
```

If I try to update a record with the same data in the **uName** field with the following statement

```
INSERT(ID, uName) VALUES (2, 'Test01') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uName = 'Test01';
```

**I receive the error:**

> Error: Duplicate entry 'Test01' for key 'uName_UNIQUE'

**Question:**

Is there an easy method managing the error or should I just remove the UNIQUE index and allow the duplication?

Comment: there should be ways to get db error from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php then u can continue your alternative flow based on the error code. I would do a check in DB to prevent the sql error. Sql error does break the flow if your php/mysql error settings in server is not done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) occurs when the primary key id is duplicated, the error shows because the update field uName is also UNIQUE. so you should remove unique index for uName.

Answer (score 0):

you can not allowing update if name already in the table

```
INSERT INTO table(ID, uName) VALUES (2, 'Test01') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uName = 'Test01' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT uName FROM table WHERE uName = 'Test01');
```